# Include Zeroes in SQL Query grouped by dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that lists issues (aka tasks) for people, and I'd like to count how many are labelled as "Closed on Time".

I am not very experienced with SQL queries to be honest, and I'm trying to just pull the data of all tasks closed in time, against the month.

Here is the (postgres) SQL query:

```
SELECT
    cast(date_trunc('month', b.closed_on) as date) AS time,
    count(distinct a.issue_id) as "Tasks Closed On Time"
from redmine_issues_summary a
left join redmine_issues_summary b on cast(date_trunc('month', b.closed_on) as date) = cast(date_trunc('month', a.closed_on) as date)
WHERE
  a.assignee_groups in('Modelling','Global') and
  a.tracker in('Administration','Costing','N.A.','Prototype Shop','Simulation') and 
  a.closed_on_time = 'On Time'
group by cast(date_trunc('month', b.closed_on) as date)
ORDER BY cast(date_trunc('month', b.closed_on) as date)
```

However, I am doing something wrong with the join, seeing as I am not getting rows where the count is zero.

Could someone help me out here?

EDIT:

@Tim's answer helped me find a solution.

```
SELECT
    cast(date_trunc('month', b.closed_on) as date) AS time,
    SUM(case when a.closed_on_time = 'On Time' and a.assignee_groups in('LOH_Modelling&Analysis','LOH_Modelling&Analysis, Global_CAE','LOH_Modelling&Analysis, KOP_CAE, Global_CAE','Project_Admin, LOH_Modelling&Analysis','Project_Admin, LOH_Modelling&Analysis, Global_CAE') and
  a.top_parent_project_name in('1_Global GKN Projects') and 
  a.tracker in('Administration') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Tasks Closed On Time"
from redmine_issues_summary a
left join redmine_issues_summary b on cast(date_trunc('month', b.closed_on) as date) = cast(date_trunc('month', a.closed_on) as date)
group by cast(date_trunc('month', b.closed_on) as date)
ORDER BY cast(date_trunc('month', b.closed_on) as date)
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data to your question, both input and output?

Comment: Is there somewhere online where I can paste it?

Comment: @Vinay87 add in your question or create https://dbfiddle.uk/

Answer (score 0):

Try using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    cast(date_trunc('month', b.closed_on) as date) AS time,
    sum(case when a.closed_on_time = 'On Time' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Tasks Closed On Time"
from redmine_issues_summary a
left join redmine_issues_summary b
    on cast(date_trunc('month', b.closed_on) as date) = cast(date_trunc('month', a.closed_on) as date)
WHERE
    a.assignee_groups in('Modelling','Global') and
    a.tracker in('Administration','Costing','N.A.','Prototype Shop','Simulation')
group by
    cast(date_trunc('month', b.closed_on) as date)
ORDER BY
    cast(date_trunc('month', b.closed_on) as date)
```

This assumes that you don't want to include *any* records which are not in the specified assignee or tracker groups.  If you *do* want to include those records, then my answer would need to be updated.

Comment: Oh! I just saw your edit. Yes please. I'd want to include date records which do not have any entries with those filters.

Comment: What was the point of even having that in the `WHERE` clause then?

Comment: Ah, I seem to have put this in a rather confusing way. Apologies.

Comment: I meant I'd like to group by the dates and see zeroes for months where there is no matching data.

Comment: This is why I asked you for sample data.  I can't read your mind, and more pressing, I can't even update my answer right now.  Hopefully I have gotten you close to what you need.

Comment: :) You did. I didn't know about conditional aggregation. This solved it nicely. Thank you!

Comment: Ah! I realized that it doesn't count distinct anymore. How do I fix that now? I tried grouping by issue id, and it failed.

Comment: Did you miss the part where we asked you for sample data?

Answer (score 0):

use left table in selection ,
you have used right table column (`b.closed_on`) in selection you need to changed that (`a.closed_on`)

```
SELECT
    cast(date_trunc('month', a.closed_on) as date) AS time,
    count(distinct a.issue_id) as "Tasks Closed On Time"
from redmine_issues_summary a
left join redmine_issues_summary b on cast(date_trunc('month', b.closed_on) as date) = cast(date_trunc('month', a.closed_on) as date)
WHERE
  a.assignee_groups in('Modelling','Global') and
  a.tracker in('Administration','Costing','N.A.','Prototype Shop','Simulation') and 
  a.closed_on_time = 'On Time'
group by cast(date_trunc('month', a.closed_on) as date)
ORDER BY cast(date_trunc('month', a.closed_on) as date)
```

Comment: Postgres says `column "a.closed_on" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: @Vinay87 yes you have to include that one